# How to change default folder in RichFileManager

Tags: php

I am trying to use RichFileManger, PHP file manager. I downloaded it and extracted it into http://localhost:8080/RichFilemanager-2.3.3, folder.

It is by default using its `userfiles` folder, and working as expected.

How can I change the default folder to http://localhost:8080/cbsadp folder. So that files in my cbsadp folder getting viewed.

I tried `"serverRoot" => false,` and `"fileRoot" => 'localhost:8080/cbsadp/'` in `RichFilemanager-2.3.3\connectors\php\config.php` ,but it give error `The file / does not exist.`

Please help.

Comment: Try setting the `baseUrl` parameter to your folder.

Comment: can you please explain in which file baseUrl is. Is it filemanager.js. I changed there but no use.

Comment: Where you define it like `$('.fm-container').richFilemanager({
        baseUrl: '.',`

Comment: I havent touched anything, its the bare setup that works like that. I am new to PHP & have some requirement for this. I you can please help me.

Comment: Do you see an index.html file?

Comment: yes  <script type="application/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $('.fm-container').richFilemanager();
            });
  </script>

Comment: Change it to `$(function() { $('.fm-container').richFilemanager({baseUrl: '/your/path'}); });`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144389/discussion-between-raju-and-gaganshera).